# Node JS Not Allowing Returned JSON into JSON String

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have written a Firebase cloud function to sign people up into my Firebase database.  I have tested with POSTMAN and the function is working correctly.

The problem I am having is that I have a function that is getting a stripe ID and then needs to return that value.  I want the customer id (customer.id in my reference) to append a JSON string I have created with the users info.

This way, when the function is done it needs to write all the data to firebase and then return the same JSON string variable to my app.  This all works, but I cannot get the Stripe ID to append into my JSON array and be parsed.

I have been cowering the internet to try and find a solution, and I believe my syntax is correct, but its not working.   I know the function is working because the console.log is outputting the stripe ID, its just not being added to the JSON variable that is being written to Firebase.

Anyone that could explain where I am going wrong would be much appreciated.  I have referenced my issue points in the code below with // for comments.

```
exports.myCloudFunction=
functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return;
    }
    const userDataInput = req.body;
    console.log('Console Body:', req.body);

    admin.auth().createUser({
        email: userDataInput.email,
        emailVerified: false,
        phoneNumber: userDataInput.mobile,
        password: userDataInput.password,
        displayName: userDataInput.firstname + ' ' + userDataInput.lastname,
        disabled: false
    })
        .then(async function (userRecord) {
            console.log('User record:', userRecord);

            var userObject =  //CONSTRUCTED JSON STRING
            {
                first_name: userDataInput.firstname,
                last_name: userDataInput.lastname,
                mobile_number: userDataInput.mobile,
                email: userDataInput.email,
                timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                driver_profile: { isDriverApproved: false, isDriverDisabled: false, isDriverStatusPending: false, isDriver: false, isPickupModeEnabled: false },
            }
            stripe.customers.create({
                description: 'Firebase ID: ' + userRecord.uid,
                email: userRecord.email,
                name: userRecord.displayName,
                phone: userRecord.phoneNumber

            }, async function (err, customer) {
                console.log('New Stripe ID Created', customer.id); // THIS WORKS< THE customer.id is outputting
                try {
                    return userObject[{ stripe_id: customer.id }];  // THIS IS NOT WORKING, I WANT **customer.id** TO BE PUT INTO THE **userObject** JSON variable.
                }
                catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    return res.status(200).send('Error: ' + error);
                }

            });

            try {
                await admin.database().ref('users/' + userRecord.uid).set(userObject);
                return res.status(200).send({ returnData: userObject });
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return res.status(200).send('Error: ' + error);
            }

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
            res.status(500).send({ returnError: error });
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the return it won't return anything because is a callback

```
exports.myCloudFunction =
    functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        if (req.method !== 'POST') {
            return;
        }
        const userDataInput = req.body;
        console.log('Console Body:', req.body);

        admin.auth().createUser({
            email: userDataInput.email,
            emailVerified: false,
            phoneNumber: userDataInput.mobile,
            password: userDataInput.password,
            displayName: userDataInput.firstname + ' ' + userDataInput.lastname,
            disabled: false
        })
            .then(async function (userRecord) {
                console.log('User record:', userRecord);

                var userObject =  //CONSTRUCTED JSON STRING
                    {
                        first_name: userDataInput.firstname,
                        last_name: userDataInput.lastname,
                        mobile_number: userDataInput.mobile,
                        email: userDataInput.email,
                        timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                        driver_profile: {
                            isDriverApproved: false,
                            isDriverDisabled: false,
                            isDriverStatusPending: false,
                            isDriver: false,
                            isPickupModeEnabled: false
                        },
                    }
                stripe.customers.create({
                    description: 'Firebase ID: ' + userRecord.uid,
                    email: userRecord.email,
                    name: userRecord.displayName,
                    phone: userRecord.phoneNumber

                }, async function (err, customer) {
                    console.log('New Stripe ID Created', customer.id); // THIS WORKS< THE customer.id is outputting
                    try {
                        // Move your logic to the final callback
                        userObject["stripe_id"] = customer.id;

                        await admin.database().ref('users/' + userRecord.uid).set(userObject);

                        return res.status(200).send({returnData: userObject});
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                        return res.status(200).send('Error: ' + error);
                    }

                });

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
                res.status(500).send({returnError: error});
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the error. There is an issue with your syntax

There is a line of code that is wrong

```
 //replace 
 return userObject[{ stripe_id: customer.id }];

 // for this
 return userObject.stripe_id = customer.id;
```

**Note:** Try to separate your code better. It's kind of hard to read